# How to get the URL the client used

Tags: asp.net

In ASP.NET, how can I know whether the user has typed the default document in the URL or not—i.e., distinguish if the URL ends with `/` or `/Default.aspx`?

Answer (score 2):

Nice problem :D unfortunately `Request.URL.AbsoluteURI` does not differentiate between the two in the default setup of IIS. IIS does a 'courtesy' redirect to the default pages existing in a web-directory, and this is done during protocol resolution -- i.e., ISAPI extensions do not see it (python framework , ASP.NET framework etc etc). You have two options :

1. Disable the courtesy redirect by unlisting `default.aspx` as default redirect, and then you will be able to use `Request.URL.AbsoluteURI`.
2. You will almost certainly not want to do this option.... Write an ISAPI filter to extract the data... perform a silent remapping (i.e., do not redirect to default.aspx, just remap the request headers') or when you redirect set a QueryString -- i.e., `abc.com/default.aspx?redirected=1`

p.s. this is what i get from three years of developing server plugins :/.